# Codility's stonewall 100% solution - different paths such as if,else if,etc, do the same thing

Tags: c#, performance, beginner, programming-challenge, stack

Here is the task description for the codility's stonewall problem. I would like to get a feedback on my code, and I specify at the bottom what the title states. (I had to make the figure by hand, because I couldn't paste the site's one for some reason, but it can be seen [here](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/7-stacks_and_queues/stone_wall/), if mine doesn't look right)

> ***Task description***

---

> You are going to build a stone wall. The wall should
>   be straight and N meters long, and its thickness should be constant;
>   however, it should have different heights in different places. The
>   height of the wall is specified by an array H of N positive integers.
>   H[I] is the height of the wall from I to I+1 meters to the right of
>   its left end. In particular, H[0] is the height of the wall's left end
>   and H[N−1] is the height of the wall's right end.
>
> The wall should be built of cuboid stone blocks (that is, all sides of
>   such blocks are rectangular). Your task is to compute the minimum
>   number of blocks needed to build the wall.
>
> Write a function:
>
> class Solution { public int solution(int[] H); }
>
> that, given an array H of N positive integers specifying the height of
>   the wall, returns the minimum number of blocks needed to build it.
>
> For example, given array H containing N = 9 integers:
>
> `H[0] = 8 H[1] = 8    H[2] = 5   H[3] = 7` 
>     `H[4] = 9 H[5] = 8    H[6] = 7   H[7] = 4    H[8] = 8`
>   the function should return 7. The shows one possible arrangement of seven 
>   blocks.
>
> [image]
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array H
>   is an integer within the range [1..1,000,000,000].

And here is my 100% O(N) time complexity solution.
As the title says, I find it kinda weird that different paths do the same thing. Should I fix that? if so... how? the logic is correct. And should I care? Thinking in bigger problems, if many paths do the same thing, and requirements change, I should change code in many places, which is not recommended.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] H) {
        Stack<int> heightsStack = new Stack<int>();
        int blocksCounter = 0;

        for (int height = 0; height < H.Length; height++)
        {
            if (heightsStack.Count > 0)
            {
                while (heightsStack.Count > 0 && heightsStack.Peek() > H[height])
                {
                    heightsStack.Pop();
                }
                if (heightsStack.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (heightsStack.Peek() < H[height])
                    {
                        blocksCounter++;
                        heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    blocksCounter++;
                    heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                blocksCounter++;
                heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
            }
        }
        return blocksCounter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of these branches can be eliminated. Let's see:

```
if (heightsStack.Count > 0)
{
  if (heightsStack.Peek() < H[height])
  {
    blocksCounter++;
    heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
  }
}
else
{
  blocksCounter++;
  heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
}
```

Here, there are two conditions where we execute the two common lines: `heightsStack.Count <= 0` or `heightsStack.Peek() < H[height]`. Since `Count`  can't be negative, let's rewrite it as such:

```
if (heightsStack.Count == 0 || heightsStack.Peek() < H[height])
{
  blocksCounter++;
  heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
}
```

---

```
if (heightsStack.Count > 0)
{
  while (heightsStack.Count > 0 && heightsStack.Peek() > H[height])
  {
```

The first if-statement is redundant. If `heightStack.Count > 0` is false, the while statement will be false as well. We would immediately fall through and end up at the if-statement in the section above. This if-statement would evaluate to true, since `heightStack.Count == 0` still. And it would execute the two common lines.

This would leave the body of the for-loop as follows:

```
while (heightsStack.Count > 0 && heightsStack.Peek() > H[height])
{
  heightsStack.Pop();
}
if (heightsStack.Count == 0 || heightsStack.Peek() < H[height])
{
  blocksCounter++;
  heightsStack.Push(H[height]);
}
```

Note, that we only have one branch with the two common lines.

---

There's one last thing. You're using a for-loop, and only using the looped variable to index directly. Instead, consider using a foreach loop:

```
public int solution(int[] H)
{
  Stack<int> heightsStack = new Stack<int>();
  int blocksCounter = 0;

  foreach(int height in H)
  {
    while (heightsStack.Count > 0 && heightsStack.Peek() > height)
    {
      heightsStack.Pop();
    }
    if (heightsStack.Count == 0 || heightsStack.Peek() < height)
    {
      blocksCounter++;
      heightsStack.Push(height);
    }
  }
  return blocksCounter;
}
```

---

As far as algorithm goes, you do what I would have come up with, so I have nothing more to say about that.